# Is there a way to limit the number of output files of a process?

Tags: c++, winapi

An application of our company uses `pdfimages` (from xpdf) to check whether some pages in a PDF files, on which we know there is no text, consist of one image.

For this we run pdfimages on that page and count whether only one, two or more, or zero output files have been created (could be JPG, PPM, PGM or PPM).

The problem is that for some PDF files, we get millions of 14-byte PPM images, and the process has to be killed manually.

We know that by assigning the process to a job we can restrict how much time the process will run for. But it would probably be better if we could control that the process will create new files at most twice during its execution.

Do you have any clue for doing that?

Thank you.

Comment: The C run-time libraries have a 512 limit for the number of files that can be open at any one time.  One solution might be to open 510 `temporary` files that do nothing, leaving you with 2 for the application. :)

Comment: Haha. But no, given that the app creates more than 512 files, I suppose it closes and opens them in sequence :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to monitor the directory for file creations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx - the monitoring app could then terminate the PDF image extraction process.

Another would be to use a simple ramdisk which limited the number of files that could be created: you might modify something like http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257405.

If you can set up a FAT16 filesystem, I think there's a limit of 128 files in the root directory, 512 in other dirs? - with such small files that would be reached quickly.

Comment: Thank you Tony. I think that watching the directory is the easiest way for us to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Also, aside from my 'joke' comment, you might want to check out `_setmaxstdio` and see if that helps ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e3b887c(VS.71).aspx ).

Comment: Would those approaches work if it created each file, then closed and reused the descriptor?  I don't see any reason to think the handles would be open concurrently.

Comment: thanks all the way, +1 for pointing to another interesting function. Even though it seems unapplicable in our case it might be of great use further.